# I asked if he wanted to meet up after all of this virus is over

Tags: meaning-in-context

I asked if he wanted to meet up after all of this virus is over.

He replied, "That's cool with me."

What does it mean when someone says "That's cool with me"? Is that like saying yes?

Comment: Yes, "that's cool with me" is an idiomatic way of saying, "yes, I'd like to do that."

Comment: Three years.... was the wait worth it? ;)

Answer (score 2):

"Cool" is a very common casual word.  It has a wide range of meanings from "stylish"  to "relaxed".  In this sense it just means "good".

"With me" means "for me" or "from my point of view".

He says your suggestion is "good for him", so he likes your idea. He is saying yes.

You didn't need to ask this question to us; you can ask him. It is not rude to ask if you don't understand something.